# How to disable ajax patching by zonejs in webcomponents

Tags: web-component, angular-elements, zonejs

we are using webcomponents in legacy project and we have an issue that zone.js patches all ajax calls which is quite bad since we don't do any ajax call by webcomponent since project limitations.

I know that it's recommended to disable zone.js in webcomponents like

```
    platformBrowserDynamic()
   .bootstrapModule(
       AppModule, { ngZone: 'noop' })
   .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

but we don't want to do it since our webcomponents is very complicated and we don't want to do change detection manually.

Is there a way how to disable only ajax patching by zone.js?